# labelling matrices in latex

Tags: matrices, labels, nicematrix, kbordermatrix

I am doing this:

```
\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
basal & prism & \pi_1 & \dots \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
Q^b\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
h_{1}^b & h_{2}^b & \dots \\
h_{2}^b & h_{1}^b & \dots \\
h_{2}^b & h_{2}^b & \ddots \\
\end{array}\right) & Q^bh^b_p & Q^bh^b_{\pi 1} & \dots\\
Q^ph^b_p & Q^p \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
h_1^p & h_2^p & \dots\\ 
h_2^p & h_1^p & \dots\\
h_2^p & h_2^p & \ddots\\
\end{array}\right) & Q^ph^p_{\pi1} & \dots \\
Q^{\pi 1} h_b^{\pi 1} & Q^{\pi 1} h_p^{\pi 1} & \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
h_1^{\pi1} & h_2^{\pi1} & \dots\\ 
h_2^{\pi1} & h_1^{\pi1} & \dots\\
h_2^{\pi1} & h_2^{\pi1} & \ddots\\
\end{array}\right) & \dots\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}\right)
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

and I am getting this:

[image]

But I want to get this instead:

[image]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have been stuck on this problem for the past three days...

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Why do you not use kbordermatrix, or nicematrix package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nicematrix` has already been [mentioned in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569318/labelling-matrices-in-latex#comment1434954_569318). You can play with the dots to make them more appealing, see the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & \text{basal} & \text{prism} & \pi_1 & \dots \\
\text{basal} & Q^b\begin{pmatrix}
  h_{1}^b & h_{2}^b & \dots \\
  h_{2}^b & h_{1}^b & \dots \\
  h_{2}^b & h_{2}^b & \ddots \\
  \end{pmatrix}& Q^bh^b_p & Q^bh^b_{\pi 1} & \dots\\
\text{prism} & Q^ph^b_p & Q^p \begin{pmatrix}
   h_1^p & h_2^p & \dots\\ 
   h_2^p & h_1^p & \dots\\
   h_2^p & h_2^p & \ddots\\
   \end{pmatrix} & Q^ph^p_{\pi1} & \dots \\
\pi_1 & Q^{\pi 1} h_b^{\pi 1} & Q^{\pi 1} h_p^{\pi 1} & 
\begin{pmatrix}
h_1^{\pi1} & h_2^{\pi1} & \dots\\ 
h_2^{\pi1} & h_1^{\pi1} & \dots\\
h_2^{\pi1} & h_2^{\pi1} & \ddots\\
\end{pmatrix} & \dots\\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]